# Update Specific cells in a tableView without calling reloadData

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have an app in which I have a `UITableview` with custom cells and headers. The cells have an inputView so when selected they become first responder and allow the user to input data. 
I want to be able to update the visible `TableViewCell` and header information on the fly while the user is changing it.. easy, just call `[tableview reloadData];` .. 
Unfortunately this causes the inputview to resign first responder and hide itself.

Is there any way that I can get a reference to the cell itself inside the `UITableview` so that I can just change the text property? (`cellForRow:atIndexPath:` returns a new object with the same properties so doesn't work) It seems like the only easy solution may be to store a reference the cells in a dictionary each time a cell is populated, not really the ideal solution.

cellForRowAtIndexPath is literally just

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomCell *orderCell;
    static NSString *productCellIdentifier = @"ImageDetailCellIdentifier";
    orderCell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:productCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

//set a bunch of properties orderCell.blah
    return orderCell;
}
```

Comment: If you're using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` it should return the existing cell if visible.

Comment: It doesn't seem to, if this were true I could just call dequeReusableCellWithIdentifier and it would update itself with the correct values. But inspecting it while in debug, the cell has default values until the line where they are set, so it seems to be a different object.

Comment: Show us you `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. The problem may be there.

Comment: I would expect that a call to `cellForRowAtIndexPath` using the SAME tableView for an indexPath that is currently visible to dequeue the visible cell that is already set up. Make sure you aren't reloading the table view before you do this.

Comment: CrimsonChris is right that you should get the same cell if it is visible, but dequeue is not relevant since dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier only returns cells that are not visible and have been recycled for reuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `UITableView` documentation, `-cellForRowAtIndexPath:` returns an object representing a cell of the table or `nil` if the cell is not visible or *indexPath* is out of range.

That is also how I remember it. I don't think your observation is correct that it returns a new object. If the cell is visible you will get hold of it.

Comment: Right, so I ended up solving this before seeing this but your observation is spot on and was how I ended up fixing the issue.

My observation about the new object was referring to the -cellForRowAtIndexPath on the UITableViewDataSource. Rather than the UITableView like you suggest, there is a subtle difference between the two and I was calling the wrong one.

Fixed it by saying 
CustomCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];
// do updates on cell...

Answer (score 1):

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade]; ///as your choice in animation
[tableView endUpdates];
```

or else

```
 [tableView beginUpdates];
// do some work what ever u need
 [tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: hmmm, this seems to have the same effect as reloadData. In that it causes the textfield within the cell to stop being first responder. Which hides the input view.

Answer (score 1):

For reloading specific rows, you can use

```
- (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation;
```

For example,

```
NSIndexPath* indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:1];
NSArray* indexArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath];

[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```